# Function changes value in sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a function which prototype is:

```
Function TableToText(ByVal Table As Range) As String
```

This function is supposed to give me a string and not modify the sheet at all. However the operations that I perform on `Table` (which is a `Range`) inside the function also modify my sheet.

I thought `ByVal` which is the default was supposed to prevent that?

I tried in my function to make another range but to make another Range you use `Set` so it wouldn't have solved the problem anyway...

Can someone point out what I am missing here? Thank you in advance! :)

---

The whole function is

```
Function TableToText(Table As Range) As String
    Dim nbColumns As Integer, nbRows As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, s As Integer
    Dim max As Integer, difference As Integer

    nbColumns = Table.Columns.Count
    nbRows = Table.Rows.Count
    With Table
    '' adding the spaces
        For j = 1 To nbColumns
            max = 0
            ' Find the longest string in the column
            For i = 1 To nbRows
                If Len(.Cells(i, j).Value) > max Then
                    max = Len(.Cells(i, j).Value)
                End If
            Next i

            ' Adding the spaces and the |
            For i = 1 To nbRows
                If Len(.Cells(i, j).Value) < max Then
                    difference = max - Len(.Cells(i, j).Value)
                    For s = 1 To difference
                        .Cells(i, j) = CStr(.Cells(i, j).Value) + " "
                    Next s
                End If
                .Cells(i, j) = CStr(.Cells(i, j).Value) + "|"
            Next i
        Next j

        '' Creating the plain text table string
        For i = 1 To nbRows
            For j = 1 To nbColumns
                TableToText = TableToText + .Cells(i, j).Value
            Next j
            TableToText = TableToText & vbCrLf
        Next i
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: @Vityata I've added it. Is there any way to change or bypass that?

Comment: The easiest way that would work - pass the range the way it is passed and convert the range to a 2 dimensioanl array. Then rewrite the function, referring to the array only. The cells would stay untouched.

Comment: It is impossible to pass an instance of a reference type truly "byval" (that is, making a copy of it), neither in VBA, nor in VB.NET, nor in C#. While you could clone a regular object manually before passing, if that was your goal, it would make no sense in the case of Excel `Range` because that object is always connected to a worksheet. It's impossible to have virtual `Range`s that point to virtual cells, so any changes made through any instance of `Range` will always modify the sheet.

Comment: @Vityata alright I will try that thank you!

Comment: @GSerg alright thank you!

Comment: You can store the range in an array and then pass that array. Anything you do in that array will not affect the range. From the looks of what you are doing, I think this is what would help you..

Comment: @Vityata thanks I used a Variant with `arr = Table.Value` to go faster and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot of misleading information and confusion on this page.

> I thought ByVal which is the default was supposed to prevent that?

The default is `ByRef` in VBA. This is unfortunate, because the vast majority of the time, what you mean to do is to pass things `ByVal`.

> Objects are always passed by reference [...] ByVal is ignored.

No. Objects are never "passed", period. What's passed byref/byval is a *reference* to the object, i.e. a pointer. **That does not mean object parameters are always passed `ByRef` at all**.

Let's debunk this claim once and for all.

```
Public Sub DebunkObjectsAreAlwaysPassedByRefClaim()
    Dim thing As Collection 'any object type will do
    Set thing = New Collection
    DoSomethingByVal thing 'we pass a COPY of the pointer
    Debug.Print thing.Count 'no problems here
    DoSomethingByRef thing 'we pass a reference to our local pointer; what could possibly go wrong?
    Debug.Print thing.Count 'error 91! the object reference is gone!
End Sub

Private Sub DoSomethingByVal(ByVal o As Object)
    Set o = Nothing 'affects the local copy only
End Sub

Private Sub DoSomethingByRef(ByRef o As Object)
    Set o = Nothing 'affects the same object pointer the caller gave us. this is bad.
End Sub
```

`ByRef` vs `ByVal` makes a major difference: give a procedure your object pointer (`ByRef`), and they can do anything they like with it - including `Set`-assigning it to a completely different object reference, or making it `Nothing`. Give a procedure *a copy of* your object pointer (`ByVal`), and whatever they do with it (including `Set`-assigning it to a completely different object reference or making it `Nothing`) will only affect *that copy*.

In both cases, whether you've passed the pointer itself or a copy of it, *either way you're giving the procedure access to the same object*, so [as GSerg explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57611311/function-changes-value-in-sheet#comment101678192_57611311), any instruction that affects a `Range` (which you can't *create* - all `Range` objects belong to Excel, all you ever get is *a pointer* to one), regardless of where the pointer comes from, will affect the `Range` instance state.

So if you don't want to affect any worksheet, don't affect any `Range` and [work with arrays instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57611678/1188513).

Answer (score 1):

Objects are always passed by reference even if you specify the byval keyword.

You should use a temporary array to store your values.
For example, something like that :

```
Function TableToText(Table As Range) As String
    Dim nbColumns As Integer, nbRows As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, s As Integer
    Dim max As Integer, difference As Integer

    nbColumns = Table.Columns.Count
    nbRows = Table.Rows.Count
    Dim tmpValues(nbRows, nbColumns) As String

    With Table
    '' adding the spaces
        For j = 1 To nbColumns
            max = 0
            ' Find the longest string in the column
            For i = 1 To nbRows
                If Len(.Cells(i, j).Value) > max Then
                    max = Len(.Cells(i, j).Value)
                End If
            Next i

            ' Adding the spaces and the |
            For i = 1 To nbRows
                If Len(.Cells(i, j).Value) < max Then
                    difference = max - Len(.Cells(i, j).Value)
                    For s = 1 To difference
                        tmpValues(i, j) = CStr(.Cells(i, j).Value) + " "
                    Next s
                End If
                tempValues(i, j) = CStr(.Cells(i, j).Value) + "|"
            Next i
        Next j

        '' Creating the plain text table string
        For i = 1 To nbRows
            For j = 1 To nbColumns
                TableToText = TableToText + tmpValues(i, j)
            Next j
            TableToText = TableToText & vbCrLf
        Next i
    End With
End Function
```

Hope it helps.